# Background not filling up

Tags: css, reactjs, background-color

```
class Landing extends Component {
  state = {
    box: {
      width: "300px",
      height: "100px",
      margin: "0 auto",
      border: "1px solid blue",
      textAlign: "center",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      lineHeight: "90px",
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },

    body: {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.body}>
        <div style={this.state.box}>Hello</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want is that the body's background be red, with a box in the middle which has a white background with text in it.

What happens is that the background of the page is not filling up, rather only a part of it. Background is red only in something like the row of the box.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `box` to be **centered** in the **middle** of the screen.

So you need `body` to fill the screen and center its children (for example with `flex`).

```
const parentStyle = {
  backgroundColor: `red`,
  height: `100vh`,
  width: `100vw`,
  display: `flex`,
  alignItems: `center`,
  justifyItems: `center`,
};
```

[image: Edit modest-zhukovsky-cbr1s]

Answer (score 1):

To make the red box fill the whole screen you have to put some css that ensures that the height of the elements surrounding the red box is 100%:

```
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The margin is so that there isn't a small white area surrounding the red box